# Java Virtual Key board

Tags: java, swing

anyone can suggest me open source java virtual key board done in swing.

Regards,
Selva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool, easy to answer: "open source java virtual key board done in swing" is a good question for google. First hit is your question, second hit (in my view) a first link to a collection on fileguru:

http://www.fileguru.com/apps/opensource_java_virtual_keyboard